# XDocument.Descendants("somethinghere").Count() method does not exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to do a simple count of some descendants using [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML) and the "Count()" method does not exist for me?

Example:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "somexmlfile" );
int count = doc.Descendants("somethinghere").Count();
```

The above won't compile, because it doesn't recognize the `Count()` method.

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file?

Comment: Nope and that fixed it! Your the man!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `Descendants(XName name)` returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

By design, IEnumerable lazy loads the data and so counting items in the collection would cause enumeration to occur.

I would probably convert this to an `IList` which has a `Count` property you can use.

Comment: I was aware of all of that its just that I found numerous examples on the net showing a XDocument.Descendants().Count() and was perplexed why I did not have that method. Now I know why thanks to svick.

Comment: If all you want to do is to count the elements, then converting to a list is overkill.

Comment: It's likely he's going to do other stuff other than just count them items though, in which case itterating twice over the collection will be overkill.